# Centos 9 stream : getting wine: could not load ntdll.so [...] Permission Denied error

Tags: wine

I wanted to install notepad++ on Centos Stream 9.
I followed tutorial as per : https://snapcraft.io/install/notepad-plus-plus/centos

I got following error when running notepad++ :

```
[sudo] password for user: 
Initialising Wine..
wine: could not load ntdll.so: /snap/notepad-plus-plus/349/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/../lib/wine/ntdll.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
wine: could not load ntdll.so: /snap/notepad-plus-plus/349/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/../lib/wine/ntdll.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
Installing application..
Running hook '/snap/notepad-plus-plus/349/sommelier/hooks/pre-install'
Starting application..
wine: could not load ntdll.so: /snap/notepad-plus-plus/349/wine-platform/wine-stable/bin/../lib/wine/ntdll.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resides in the part that reads :
`cannot restore segment prot after reloc: Permission denied`

This problem occurs because SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux) is installed on the machine. The SELinux configuration is preventing the shared library "ntdll.so" from loading.

To solve it only during the current session:
`[user@localhost bin]$ /usr/sbin/setenforce 0`

You should then be able to run wine fine.

To solve it permanently, have a look at the following for more details :
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-cannot-restore-segment-prot-after-reloc-permission-denied-during-linux-installation